# How to add a path to a directory with an external dll in maven

Tags: java, maven

I added the path to the directory with dll in intellij IDEA: File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings ->Libraries and it was displayed with name "lib", classes "E:\project...\libs". 
If I run with using idea, then everything works. 
After building the jar file I run and get an exception:  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'MyDll.dll': Native library (win32-x86-64/MyDll.dll) not found in resource path.

How do I configure a pom file using spring-boot-maven-plugin so that path to dll is in the classpath?

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a system dependency, for example:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>mydep</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/mydep-1.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

but it's not recommended, you should publish your dependencies in a repository like nexus